# Whats the best video camera for shooting weddings and Docs?

Tags: video-recording

I was just wondering what would be the best professional Video Camera for shooting weddings and documentaries? I have a Canon 6D but want to invest in a prosumer camera that I can move around and keep focus. I find it awkward that you cant digitally zoom in to check focus on the 6D when its recording.

I was looking at the Canon C100 but its not very ergonomically designed for run and gun shooting. That said with the Atmos Ninja it can be every bit as good as its big brother the C500. Has anyone used this for weddings.

Is there anything in particular that would be a deal breaker on a camera. Ie no XLR's, a noisy internal zoom.

Should I invest in gear that can shoot 4K? I want to steer clear of Mini DV and i have a macbook pro with 16 gb RAM and an i7 processor.

I'm thinking of spending between 3000 - 3500 Euro on it as it'll need to last me for years.

I'd really appreciate any information you can give. Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for product recommendations are of-topic for Video Production, as the answers tend to be opinion based, and become outdated very quickly.

Comment: There isn't enough information here and the subject changes fairly regularly.  You can hop in chat if you want to discuss current models or you can ask another question here if you want to focus in on what the key features for wedding videos are and comparing the strengths and weaknesses of various types of cameras (such as DSLRs vs CMOS sensor video vs CCD video).  You may also want to consider looking at questions about how to better shoot on Canon DSLRs such as those talking about Magic Lantern or take a look at whatever is current in Black Magic's line up as well.

Answer (score 1):

I shoot weddings and currently use a Canon 7D with a Zoom lens, it is all up to how you shoot and feel when shooting, I like the 7D as it is small and doesnt look to intrusive, I would like to upgrade to the Canon C100 as it would give me better options but still stay in the small form.

It is all down to personal preference in the end, You could just hire a few out and see if you like to feel, form factor etc as some people would say go ARRI and others would be DSLR route

Answer (score -1):

"Best" is kind of a vague request.  Based on what you wrote about your shooting,  maybe you should look at the Canon 5dmkIII, or the Sony A7S.  Both have superior video, and are well-suited for run-and-gun.

Comment: If he is saying the C100 isn't ergonomic enough, then a DSLR isn't really what he is looking for either.  The C100 basically is a DSLR that is designed specifically for video.  The traditional solution in that case is to build rigging to go around the camera itself.  True run and gun shooting requires either using a steadicam rig or a shoulder rig (or at least something that provides 3 points of contact, such as a zFinder.)